# Xcode using Storyboard to create ipad app is a headache

Tags: xcode, storyboard

Well my question is simple how to use xcode's storyboards on a macbook pro 13 inch when you want to create an app for Ipad. The views are just too big to fit in the interface and you can't see easily the view because it's just to zoomed in and if you are zooming out you can't add in that view ..

Comment: You can set the app as universal and use the iPhone storyboard and it will work for iPad you will have more space to work other wise connect a external screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No good answer here. It is a frustrating exercise, lots of zooming in and out.

1. Obviously, make the most of the screen:

   - minimizing panels you don't need;
   - put Xcode in "full screen" mode (which temporarily hides the menu and maximizes your screen real-estate); and
   - removing text labels from the toolbar or hiding it altogether (and hiding tab bar if you use that).
2. You can obviously make sure that if you do have to zoom in and out, do so efficiently:

   - using keyboard shortcuts (and, if you want, define your own keyboard bindings by going into "Settings" - "Key bindings", search for zoom, and add whatever additional keyboard bindings you want);
   - pinch-zooming with trackpad; and
   - double clicking on the background of the storyboard to zoom in and out, etc.
3. I also use the Interface Builder document outline more, too.

   - When I'm done with the annoying process of the visual layout of the scene, I select controls for `IBOutlet`, `IBAction`, and other settings using the document outline (that panel of the left side of the main IB panel)
   - When I select a control in the document outline, IB will scroll it into view, too.
   - If you want to make this process efficient, you'll get in the habit of giving meaningful "Document" labels in the "Identity Inspector" utility panel, that way the document outline will bear meaningful labels that will make it easy for you to select the desired control quickly.
   - Using these labels also makes it easier to use the search box at the bottom of the document outline. Again, rather than zooming out a couple of times, finding the scene in question, zooming in to the control in question, I just search for it in the document outline now that I have meaningful labels there.
   - As an aside, once you use labels for your controls, identifying/interpreting autolayout constraints becomes a far simpler exercise, too (if you use autolayout).

In the end, I just got an external monitor for when I use my laptop at my desk (and the two monitor setup makes for a better experience overall, anyway).

By the way, the WWDC 2012 video [Working Efficiently with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=402) or WWDC 2013 video [Xcode Core Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/#401) includes all sorts of Xcode techniques for working efficiently, some of which are relevant to working on a small screen.